# Symfony - pass data from other entity

Tags: php, mysql, api, symfony

I want to set my registration call within User entity
registration call should receive iso code that is field in Country entity.
The system will find country by iso code and set it in User.
So country in User is relation to Country entity.

It returns null when it should return some value..

My register api call..

```
 public function registerUser($country)
{
    $user = new User();

    $country = $this->findCountry(['iso']);
    $user->setCountry($country);

    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();

    return $user;
}
```

And an api call for my Country entity..

```
public function findCountry($iso)
{
    $country = $this->getCountryRepository()->findBy([
        'iso' => $iso
    ]);
}
```

and my user enitty class

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Groups({"user_data"})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $country;
```

Comment: Is this the *real* code? I mean, is `iso` (literal) what you're searching for?

Comment: yes, that is the name of my entity field.

Comment: No, that way you're searching for something that *has* the *iso* value as value: you're not retrieving anything but that and so I doubt you get anything but `null` back from the repository

Comment: Yes, I get it now but I need some guidelines for specific problem.

Comment: You claim `It returns null when it should return some value..`. I've pointed out the issue here (you're searching for something that is not in the table, so you'll get a `null` back). You need to search for something that's in the table. You said that's an API call, right? Pull the iso code from the call (querystring parameter? posted parameter? We can't know without all relevant code) and pass it to the repository.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to solve it.

Comment: You're welcome. If you make any progress but still don't succeed, please update the question (edit it) in order to include more details. And welcome to StackOverflow as I can notice you're a new user!

Comment: I will try my best. Thanks, I am new user. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your registerUser method probably needs to have the iso as a parameter and not the country

And then you should pass that iso as a parameter to your findCountry call instead of passing the literal 'iso' that probably does not correspond to any countries.

That is why you get no values from the repository.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer. Moreover this should add some details not repeat things being said previously. Please, improve the answer, delete it or comment in the question by adding some value to other comments. Thanks.

Comment: iso is a name of a column in my country table if that changes anything

Comment: @DonCalisto Comments are comments. not answers. I provided full description of what is wrong with Filip's code. If you think it is incomplete please tell me how and I will be happy to provide that info.

Comment: @Filip, how you get the user's country by passing just the column? Don't you also need to pass it the actual user's iso value?

Comment: Ok, can I do that by writing a query where I can set that param?

Comment: You do not have to write a new query. The repository call to getCountryRepository()->findBy does just that. You just have to pass the actual value as the $iso parameter. This is done when you call $this->findCountry